# Update multiple xml nodes at once in coldfusion?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing

I have a xml document and I want to update multiple nodes at once. I am currently doing like this:

```
<cfset local.xml = xmlParse(filePath)>
<cfset local.column = xmlSearch(local.xml, "//COLUMN")>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(local.column)#" index="i">
  <cfset local.xml.DATA.HEADER.COLUMN[i].xmlAttributes.ID = i>
</cfloop>
```

This will add a attribute to each COLUMN node. But here the complexity is `O(n)`.

So it is possible to do the same in `O(1)`?

I tried like this but it is selecting only the first node:

```
<cfset local.xml = xmlParse(filePath)>
<cfset local.xml.DATA.HEADER.COLUMN.xmlAttributes.ID = 1>
```

XML SAMPLE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <HEADER>
    <COLUMN/>
    <COLUMN/>
    <COLUMN/>
    <COLUMN/>
    <COLUMN/>
    <COLUMN/>
  </HEADER>
</DATA>
```

Please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need to loop as per your first example. What is the issue with doing this?

Comment: For more data it is taking long time to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This will add a attribute to each COLUMN node. But here the complexity
>   is O(n).
>
> So it is possible to do the same in O(1)?

No.

You want to do something *for every one of N nodes*. That's *O(n)* no matter how you turn it.

You can make it *look* a bit nicer, but that's about it.

```
<cfset local.xml = XmlParse(filePath)>
<cfset local.columns = XmlSearch(local.xml, "//COLUMN")>

<cfloop array="#local.columns#" index="local.col">
  <cfset local.col.xmlAttributes.ID = i>
</cfloop>
```

---

If you want to speed up the process, there are two possibilities:

1. If adding an ID (that basically is nothing but a counter) is what you really do... Think about simply not doing it. It looks like a pretty useless operation. XML nodes have a natural order, they don't need an attribute that states their position.
2. Use a faster XML processing tool to do it. [XSLT could be worth a try](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/XmlTransform), for complex transformations in any case.

To give all `<COLUMN>` elements an ID in ascending order, you could use this transformation:

```
<!-- sample.xsl -->
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="COLUMN">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="ID">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::COLUMN) + 1" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

and this ColdFusion call

```
<cfset outputXml = XmlTransform(xmlFilePath, ExpandPath("sample.xsl"))>
```

...but if that's actually faster than the `<cfloop>` you would have to measure yourself.